# Make product comparison table from the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 19
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Hard Disk
                        [name] => harddisk
                        [value] => 500 GB
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => RAM
                        [name] => ram
                        [value] => 16 GB
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Graphics
                        [name] => graphics
                        [value] => 2 GB
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Graphics Card
                        [name] => graphicscard
                        [value] => 2 GB
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 20
        [attributes] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Hard Disk
                        [name] => harddisk
                        [value] => 1 TB
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => RAM
                        [name] => ram
                        [value] => 8 GB
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Graphics
                        [name] => graphics
                        [value] => 1 GB
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Graphics Card
                        [name] => graphicscard
                        [value] => 1 GB
                    )

            )

    )

 )
```

I want to extract this array to tabular form as :

```
  Product ID      |  19           |   20
  Hard Disk       |  500 GB       |   1 TB
  RAM             |  16 GB        |   8 GB
  Graphics        |  2 GB         |   1 GB
  Graphics Card   |  2 GB         |   1 GB
```

There may come another product id also as it is dynamic. I am able to get first column but how to get other column. My code is:

```
  <table class="table">

                <?php
                $count = count($all);
                if (!empty($all)) {
                    foreach ($all as $value) {
                        ?>
    <?php foreach ($value['attributes'] as $val) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $val['label']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                        } exit();
                    }
                }
                ?>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always completely baffled by the mixing of HTML and PHP. I prefer a clearer look.

I would solve your problem in two steps:

1: Turn your array into an array that can easily be rendered as a table.

2: Render the table from that array.

```
if (is_array($all)) {

  // step 1: create table
  foreach ($all as $one) {
    $id = $one['product_id'];
    $table['Product Id'][$id] = $id;
    foreach ($one['attributes'] as $attribute) {
      $label = $attribute['label'];
      $value = $attribute['value'];
      $table[$label][$id] = $value;
    }
  }

  // step 2: render the table
  echo '<table class="table">'.PHP_EOL;
  foreach ($table as $label => $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>$label</td>";
    foreach ($table['Product Id'] as $id) {
      echo '<td>'.(isset($row[$id]) ? $row[$id] : '-').'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
  }
  echo '</table>'.PHP_EOL;

}
```

This routine can cope with missing attributes.

This code is not perfect, but it gives you a point to start. The challenge is to reduce the complexity even more. I think that's possible.

Comment: Hi, I found bugs in it. I cannot access product id to get rows from database  based on product id.

Comment: The code was tested with your example array, and it worked. I have called product id `$id`, and it seems accessible to me. Anyway, the code here is only meant to give you new ideas, you can use a completely different way to solve this problem if you have needs that you didn't specify in your question.

Comment: I am trying to get product details from the database using the product id. Yes I can access the product id but since it is in loop, database query are taking more times as many loop as it runs. Can you please help me in requesting database only two times since in question there is only two product id. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please submit a new question about database access. You should not change the topic of an existing question. That will also give other people again a change to help you.